# Density of square-free values of polynomials of degree $1$ over integers.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm reading an article by Dan Carmon on Square-free values of large polynomials over the rational function field and whilst investigating its meaning, I started reading a proof showing that

> The 'probability' that a large random integer is square-free is $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

I know I haven't defined probability and density explicitly, but hope you understand its meaning anyway. It made use of the following

> Given two random integers from $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}, n\in \mathbb{N}$. The asymptotic probability that they are relative prime as $n\to \infty$ is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$.

**My question is the following:**

If we look at polynomials of degree $1$, the above clearly proves that the density of square-free values of the polynomial $f(x) = x$ (over the integers) is $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. However, why it this the case for **every** polynomial of degree $1$? (and seeing the comment below, it this even true?)

Comment: I'd expect that being square-free and being in an arithmetic progression are independent events and so the probability of $ax+b$ being  square-free should be $\frac{1}{a}\frac{6}{\pi^2}$

Comment: Any thoughts on how I can prove this?

Comment: I think in particular, **the probability that two random integers are relatively prime (coprime) is** $\frac{6}{\pi^2}$. But for sufficiently large integers, I believe you are correct :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paper [A Note on Square‐Free Numbers in Arithmetic Progressions](https://doi.org/10.1112/blms/7.2.133), Hooley says:

[image]

The paper by Prachar is [Über die kleinste quadratfreie Zahl einer arithmetischen Reihe](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01301288).